# I can't switch boot drive to another drive properly?

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd

I have a KINGSTON Disk(DISK 2 E:) and a Samsung(Disk 1 C:), my OS is located on the C: Drive(Disk 1).

I know how to clone the drives, i use ASUS CloneDrive. But when i have cloned the drive to (Disk 2) the "Windows Boot Manager" on Disk 2 in the BiOS is gone.

But when i remove the SATA connection from Disk 1 it can boot from Disk 2 but just without Disk 1.

I have tried formatting the Disk 1 drive but i coulden't.

Motherboard: ASUS ROG Rampage VI EXTREAME -
Disk 1: Samsung SSD 850 EVO 500GB -
Disk 2: Kingston SKC100 480GB

Comment: This might be a trivial point, but you understand that the motherboard is what determines the booting order. Not which sata cables go to which drive. You have to tell the bios which drive you want to boot from.

Comment: @Sickest I also do/did, but when DISK 1 i pluged in I can't choese the "Kingston(DISK 2) (Windows Boot Manager)". There is only a Windoes Boot Manager for Disk 1.

Comment: Might be a good idea to point out to people which Motherboard you're working with, because that is the core of the issue here. Not the drives imo.

Comment: @Sickest Now I have written it

Comment: The bootloaders reside in the ESP (EFI System Partition). If you didn't cloned that one as well that happens. Cloning "C:\" isn't enough, you need to understand UEFI, how it works and how it boots.